# use specific cell value as address for next action

Tags: excel, vba

I've been messing and searching for a while, but am not capable enough.

- I want to select a range from `L7` to where the value in the cell is 'Anchorsec' (also column L).
- You can apparently sort of do it like this, and `EndCell` does contain the value *AnchorSec*, but how do i use  cell address of `EndCell`?

*code*

```
Dim EndCell As Range

Set EndCell = ActiveSheet.Range("L7:L30").Find("AnchorSec", LookIn:=xlValues)
ActiveSheet.Range("L7:EndCell.Adress").Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("K7:EndCell.Address.Offset(0, -1)").Paste
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Find` returns a reference to the required cell, so use that

```
Dim EndCell As Range

Set EndCell = ActiveSheet.Range("L7:L30").Find("AnchorSec", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not EndCell Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("L7", EndCell).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("K7", EndCell.Offset(0, -1)).Paste
Else
    ' AnchorSec Not Found
End If
```

Not: for any unspecified options, Find uses whatever was last used, so you should specify *all* options to ensure you get what you expect

Comment: Great, that almost works.

Funny thing; It copies, but doesn't paste ... ''Object doesnt support this property or method''

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("L7:L30").Find("AnchorSec", LookIn:=xlValues).Address
```

?

also its good to use

```
LookAt:=xlWhole
```

Answer (score 0):

use `xlFormulas` rather than `xlValues` as this works on hidden cells.

I've simplified the copying part as well

*code*

```
Set EndCell = ActiveSheet.Range("L7:L30").Find("AnchorSec", , xlFormulas, xlWhole)
If Not EndCell Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("L7", EndCell).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("K7")
Else
    MsgBox "Cell not found", vbCritical
End If
```

*Find*

`Find` takes nine parameters

> What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat

To tighten up the advice on another answer only four of these are saved by default

> LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte